# Finding a deterministic Finite state machine for the language given

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the deterministic finite state machine which accepts the following language:

$$L =\{0^i 1 0^j \mid i,j\ge 1\} \cup \{0^k \mid k\ge 3\}$$

It is easy to find a deterministic FSM that accepts individually these two languages. That much I can do. But I am not able to find a deterministic FSM that accepts the union of these two languages. Even their starting alphabet $0$ is the same. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Notice first that every word in $L$ has length at least $3$. The words in $\{0^i10^j:i,j\ge 1\}$ are the words of length at least $3$ that begin and end with $0$ and contain exactly one $1$; those in $\{0^k:k\ge 3\}$ are the words of length at least $3$ that contain no $1$ at all. Thus, $L$ is the set of words over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ that are of length at least $3$, begin and end with $0$, and contain at most one $1$. From that description it’s not too hard to come up with a suitable deterministic DFM.

Alternatively, you could combine deterministic FSMs for the two parts of $L$ into a single non-deterministic FSM by merging their initial states and letting an initial input of $0$ go into either of them, and then use the standard algorithm for converting a non-deterministic FSM to an equivalent deterministic FSM.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. First I found a non deterministic FSM and then converted it into deterministic FSM

Comment: @Shivam: You're welcome.